# How to update oracle list column with sequence number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have the oracle data table like that

| seq_no | name | place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rian | Us |
| 1 | Moli | Us |
| 1 | Molina | Us |

and i want to update automaticly the seq_no to be like that

| seq_no | name | place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rian | Us |
| 2 | Moli | Us |
| 3 | Molina | Us |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (seq_no, name, place) AS
SELECT 1, 'Rian',   'Us' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Moli',   'Us' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Molina', 'Us' FROM DUAL;
```

and a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE your_sequence;
```

Then you can update the existing rows to the sequence values using:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET seq_no = your_sequence.NEXTVAL;
```

Then the table would contain:

> | SEQ_NO | NAME | PLACE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Rian | Us |
> | 2 | Moli | Us |
> | 3 | Molina | Us |

Then when you want to `INSERT` more rows, you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (seq_no, name, place)
VALUES (your_sequence.NEXTVAL, 'New Name', 'New Place');
```

and the row:

> | SEQ_NO | NAME | PLACE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | New Name | New Place |

Would be added with the next sequence number.

Alternatively, you could write a trigger to get the next sequence number or, from Oracle 12, use an `IDENTITY` column.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aeddc386fc6e543487c4b09d6cd61968)*

Answer (score 0):

What does "automatically" mean?

You could have created table so that `SEQ_NO` is automatically populated by a **database trigger** (can't use an identity column as you're on 11g).

Or, if you want to update the table, a simple option is

```
update your_table set seq_no = rownum;
```